# Parent object with circular linked list of subobjects of same type

Tags: c, doubly-linked-list, self-reference

Every time I create a `Node`, I want to be able to add it to a doubly linked list of `Node`s that belongs to it's parent `Node`.

I've done similar things in the past but it was usually a `List` object that contained a `Node` with `previous` and `next` pointers. That same `Node` would be used as a sentinel.

This time is different because everything is of the same type and I'm having a hard time figuring out how to assemble everything correctly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node Node;

struct Node {
    Node * parent;
    Node * nodes_previous;
    Node * nodes_next;
    Node * previous;
    Node * next;
    int value;
};

Node *
Node_create(Node * const parent, int const value) {
    Node * const node = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    *node = (Node) {
        .parent = parent,
        .nodes_previous = node,
        .nodes_next = node,
        .previous = parent->nodes_previous,
        .next = parent,
        .value = value,
    };
    parent->nodes_previous->next = node;
    parent->nodes_previous = node;
    return node;
}

int
main() {

    Node parent = {
        .nodes_previous = &parent,
        .nodes_next = &parent,
    };

    (void)Node_create(&parent, 1);
    (void)Node_create(&parent, 2);
    (void)Node_create(&parent, 3);

    // Iterating forward
    for (Node * cur = parent.nodes_next; cur != &parent; cur = cur->next) {
        printf("Value: %d\n", cur->value);
    }

    // Iterating backwards
    for (Node * cur = parent.nodes_previous; cur != &parent; cur = cur->previous) {
        printf("Value: %d\n", cur->value);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you need five pointers - this is a regular (horizontal) doubly-linked list, plus a (vertical) parent pointer, right? What is the logical relationship supposed to be?

Comment: @Useless 1 pointer for the parent, 2 for keeping track of its sub nodes, and 2 more for linking nodes between themselves. Every node can be a parent to any node, and every node needs to keep track of its sub nodes.

Comment: @Useless, the relationship is always a pyramid, not a graph

Comment: So I can understand up (parent), down (child), next and prev (siblings). It's not obvious why you need both `next`/`prev` and `nodes_next`/`nodes_prev` in your code.

Comment: @Useless, picture it like this: a `type` has a `supertype` and a `supertype` has a list of its direct `subtypes`, `nodes_next` and `nodes_prev` are like the `head` and `last` of the `supertype` `subtypes` while `next` and `prev` are used to chain types together. As for the relationship that I'm trying to model is that of single type inheritance.

Comment: How are the "supertype subtypes" different from the types "chained" to the single node I'm looking at? You're claiming my parent's children are a distinct set from my own siblings. If you have _two_ horizontal relationships, then explain what they are.

Comment: There's only one horizontal relationship and that's the linked list of subtypes that belong to the supertype, but those subtypes themselves can be supertypes of a type and they also need their own linked list of subtypes and so on. I've already tried to model it with 3 pointers and it did not work. I was able to make it work with 5 and correctly (different code from here), but I'm trying to see if there's some way of doing it in a circular manner in order to avoid if statements checking for the head / last node.

Comment: Right, so I _think_ you're keeping the head and tail pointers of the child linked-list. Is that right? It's not at all obvious why you use `nodes_next` and `nodes_prev` instead of something like `children_head` and `children_tail` if that's the case, and your clarification didn't help. Anyway, there is only one sensible approach IMO ...

Comment: A doubly-linked list is a doubly-linked list. A doubly-linked list of children is not inherently different to a doubly-linked list of siblings. So don't write all your linked list operations twice, once for each relationship. Abstract it out into a reusable type, so you can work on `node->children` or `node->siblings` or whatever with the same functions.